# Reset an input field to pristine without form wrapper

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How do I reset an angular input element to pristine with no data? My model is an object.

In my current version ([Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jenpxg)) the data is reset once but the view model is not properly updated the second time around.

[image: v0][image: v1][image: v2]

I've encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280558/557552) on stackoverflow but the primary answer relies on using a wrapper form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code with my answer.

You can see the full code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdajaw

Only thing I changed is (and I strongly recommend it) instead of timeout, I use ChangeDetectorRef to wait for angular change detection to run. After change detection you can select the added input to focus.

Here is the changed `AppComponent`:

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Note } from './note.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public notes: Note[] = [];
  public newNote = new Note();

  constructor(
    protected renderer: Renderer2,
    private cRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notes.push(new Note({ content: 'foo' }));
    this.notes.push(new Note({ content: 'bar' }));
  }

  newLine(note: string) {

  // Switch it up
  this.notes.push(new Note(this.newNote));

  // Select our original element
  // setTimeout(() => this.renderer.selectRootElement('#note'+(this.notes.length-1)).focus(), 0);

  // use ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges method to wait for angular to go through change detection
  this.cRef.detectChanges();
  // after change detection you can select the added input to focus
  this.renderer.selectRootElement('#note' + (this.notes.length - 1)).focus()

  // Reset the new line
  //this.newNote = new Note();
  this.newNote = new Note({content: null});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Functionally that's exactly what I want. I do still wonder if it's possible to reset an input element without form wrapper to it's pristine state.